# How can I use the AllenNLP framework to embed a label?

Tags: embed, allennlp

Just like using "textfieldembedder" to embed "textfieldtensors", I want to embed labels and convert them into tensors with the same dimension as embedded input texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about `LabelField`? Just put the appropriate `LabelField`s into your instances, and AllenNLP will add the labels to the vocabulary for you. When `Model.__init__()` runs, you can query the size of the label namespace to find out how big to make your embedding matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a normal `torch.nn.Embedding` in your model, and as Dirk suggests, set its size based on the vocabulary's size for the label field during `Model.__init__`.